# CSRF in plugin dashboard widget 400 error

Tags: plugin-development, csrf, dashboard-widgets, cp-dashboard

Yes, it's another csrf question, the standard, *400 Error - Bad Request: Unable to verify your data submission.*

If in `config/general.php` I set `'enableCsrfProtection' => false,` then everything works nicely. So it's definitely a csrf problem.

Here's the twig template for the widget:

```
src/templates/_components/widgets/Livestream_body.twig
---------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName|e('js') }}";
    window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken|e('js') }}";
</script>
```

and the Javascript:

```
src/assetbundles/livestreamwidget/dist/js/Livestream.js
-------------------
$(document).ready(function () {
   var data = [];
   data[window.csrfTokenName] = window.csrfTokenValue;
   $.post('actions/livestream/main/manage-get', data, function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       alert('Posted OK!'); 
   });
});
```

I can see the csrf token value changes on page load, and as I said, without csrf enabled, the js successfully loads the widget, so, what am I doing wrong on the csrf? I don't have any  element. Would that make a difference?

Comment: what happen if you wrap your js code in document.ready? maybe request is sent before variable assignment in twig?

Comment: @user677900 Sorry, it is. I showed that in the question now.

Comment: with developer tools in FF, can you see csrf param sent for that request and is it as same as window.csrfTokenValue and window.csrfTokenName in inspector tab?

Comment: @user677900 I can see window.csrfTokenValue/Name but the params tab is blank. It says "No parameters for this request."

Comment: I tried sticking the token in manually as a parameter to the post URL, like this, but it didn't help: `$.post('index.php?p=admin/actions/livestream/main/manage-get/&CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN='+window.csrfTokenValue, data, function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {...`

Comment: i think in your posted code it has to be var data = {} not var data = []

Comment: Thank you so much, kind person. I've been fighting with this for three days, and now it works! If you want to post a solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [jQuery docs says](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) you have to pass data object or string via data.
so you should change

```
var data = [];
```

to

```
 var data = {};
```

in your code